# Repeat a SQL instruction until it gets all the data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a small issue trying to get some data on SQL , I've tried to do a "for" loop without succeeding and I'm getting frustrated. I've a table called "dbo.AccountTree" which has 2 columns , "ParentAccountID" and "SubAccountID".

A "ParentAccountID" can have multiple "SubAccountID's" i.e. "ParentAccountID" 101520 has 9 "SubAccountID's" but 1 of them is the same "ParentAccountID"

```
ParentAccountID SubAccount
101520          101520
101520          1201
101520          1202
101520          1203
101520          1204
101520          1205
101520          1206
101520          1207
101520          1208
```

Everything should be good except that some "SubAccountIDs" are also "ParentAccountID's" and I also need to get the "SubAccountID's" for them

```
ParentAccount   SubAccount
1204            1001
1205            1002
```

Also, those "SubAccountID's" are also "ParentAccountIDs"

```
ParentAccount   SubAccount
1002            999
```

On the above explanation , the "ParentAccountID" 101520 has 3 levels of data within the same table and I need to instruct SQL to return the "SubAccountID's" under each level ( there will be some "ParentAccountID's" with more than 3 levels so somehow the sql needs to run until all "SubAccountIDs" dont have any other level of data)

Comment: Please do not use images for textual data, for tables a `<pre>` block works very well (images are too hard to read)

Comment: "images are too hard to read" - especially for those who use assisstive technologies, such as screen readers, to access this site.

Comment: is there a max number of level ?

Comment: Fortunately if one actually reads the question, the specific data isn't too important for this question IMO; however, above comments are correct:  Pictures of text are of no use.

Comment: I've fixed the images using <pre> instead and there are no max number of levels

Answer (score 2):

You'd use a CTE, something like this should work.

```
WITH AccountTreeCTE(ParentAccountID, SubAccountID,  Depth) AS   
(  
    SELECT ParentAccountID, SubAccountID, 0 AS Depth  
    FROM dbo.AccountTree   
    WHERE ParentAccountID IS NULL  
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT e.ParentAccountID, e.SubAccountID, Depth + 1  
    FROM dbo.AccountTree AS e  
        INNER JOIN AccountTreeCTE AS d  
        ON e.ParentAccountID = d.SubAccountID   
)  
SELECT ParentAccountID, SubAccountID,  Depth   
FROM AccountTreeCTE  
ORDER BY ParentAccountID;  
GO
```

Comment: If I execute that code I'm getting no results, I've replaced "Where ParentAccountID is NULL"  with "Where ParentAccountID=240345" and I'm getting the following error: The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: @Samoya - we need to stop the circular links from being chased. Are the only cycles possible in your data where a `ParentAccountID` references *itself* as the SubAccountID? If so, adding `WHERE ParentAccountID != SubAccountID` to both `union`ed queries will be enough. Otherwise we need a cycle detector and those aren't fun to add.

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not have procedural concepts like "for loops"; I realize you're trying to relate what you need to something you know, but it's important to understand that SQL is a very different type of language than C#, Java, etc.

What SQL does have for situations like this are recursive queries.  Support for these (and the syntax) tends to depend on the DBMS; from tags it looks like you're using SQL Server, so here's an SO question about T-SQL recursive queries:

[T-SQL recursive query - how to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257615/t-sql-recursive-query-how-to-do-it)